# How to convert day/mon/year hour:min:sec to format to be inserted into mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am getting `5/10/2014 18:12:22` datetime in my `$_POST['start']` and `19/10/2014 18:12:22` datetime in my `$_POST['end']`. on using code

```
if(isset($_POST['start'])) if(!empty($_POST['start'])) $start1=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['start']);
if(isset($_POST['end'])) if(!empty($_POST['end'])) $end1=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['end']);
echo $start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start1)); //returns 2014-05-10 18:12:22
echo '<br>';
echo $end   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end1));  //returns 1970-01-01 00:00:00
die();
```

I don't no where i'm doing this wrongly so please
help any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's because PHP expects the month to be the first part of the date, i.e.: `19/10/2014`  should be `10/19/2014`.

Comment: Just use varchar for field type to store the date.

Comment: thanks @silkfire .can you please tell me about how convert this format to correct one?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 Goodness me, never use a varchar to store a date if you can avoid it at any cost! Always use a proper date data type!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pertinent column is `DATETIME/TIMESTAMP` in your table, alternatively you could also use the `DateTime` Class to reformat those dates before insertion:

Simple Example:

```
$start1 = '5/10/2014 18:12:22'; // $_POST['start'];
$end1 = '19/10/2014 18:12:22'; // $_POST['end'];

$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($start, 'd/m/Y H:i:s'); // feed the proper format so that it will be recognized.
$end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($end1, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');

$start = $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end = $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Was about to suggest the same thing given the input mask :) +1

Comment: Brilliant solution, I like that it doesn't rely on any regex either.

Comment: @Fluffeh yes i agree, very suitable in this particular situation

Comment: @Ghost can you please tell me the procedural way to do this i'm not familiar with oops format.and thanks for this briliant answer

Comment: @Anonymous actually its not much different at all. im being honest. look `date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $start);` its just the same

Comment: @Anonymous actually if you really want the procedural style you could consult the manual here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php im glad this helped